# What is the difference in declaring variables and data types

Tags: c#

I am currently creating a software application and I wonder if there is a difference in speed in performance in declaring variables. I am currently using this two different methods.

This is the first method that I use in declaring variables:

```
int productID, itemQuantity, cashAmount;
```

This is the second method that I use in declaring variables:

```
int productID;
int itemQuantity;
int cashAmount;
```

I wonder what's the best method to use in declaring variables, the first or the second.

Comment: Both are completely the same.

Comment: I'd assume it will compile to exactly the same. There will be no difference in speed.

Comment: no difference in speed, just coding style

Comment: You should stop thinking in performance categories. That's the last thing you should care when you learn to write working, readable, reliable and clean software.

Comment: Seems odd to tell someone else that they shouldn't ask a question about performance.

Comment: The most important is that you always use the same technique throughout the project to ensure consistency

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

```
int productID, itemQuantity, cashAmount;
```

is just a shorthand for the programmer for

```
int productID;
int itemQuantity;
int cashAmount;
```

and is compiled to the exact same result (IL-code):

```
.locals init ([0] int32 productID,
         [1] int32 itemQuantity,
         [2] int32 cashAmount)
```

(The indices vary depending on whether there's more local variables)

Comment: this sounds more like a comment than an answer

Comment: What exactly is this answer missing which would need expounded upon? Have my upvote.

Comment: @Adrian: Thanks